# How can I index this MongoDB table for searching?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a collection of 'clients' that have a data structure like this and I need to search based on First Name, Last Name, or DOB at the root level or in the `AlternateClientData` records:

```
{
    "_id" : GUID,
    "FirstName" : "string",
    "LastName" : "string",
    "DateOfBirth" : "YYYY-MM-dd",
    "AlternateClientData" : [ 
        {
            "AccountId" : GUID,
            "FirstName" : "string",
            "LastName" : "string",
            "DateOfBirth" : "string",
        }, 
    ]
}
```

I'm using the C# Mongo driver and the search query looks roughly like this:

```
"filter": {
    "AlternateClientData": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "AccountId": {
          "$ne": null,
          "$in": [ /* one or many account IDs */]
        }
      }
    },
    "$or": [
      {
        "FirstName": {
          "$regex": "^FName",
          "$options": "i"
        }
      },
      {
        "AlternateClientData": {
          "$elemMatch": {
            "FirstName": {
              "$regex": "^FName",
              "$options": "i"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "LastName": {
          "$regex": "^LName",
          "$options": "i"
        }
      },
      {
        "AlternateClientData": {
          "$elemMatch": {
            "LastName": {
            "$regex": "^LName",
              "$options": "i"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "DateOfBirth": "1970-01-01"
      },
      {
        "AlternateClientData": {
          "$elemMatch": {
            "DateOfBirth": "1970-01-01"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

I tried adding an index like this but mongo doesn't use it:

```
{
    "FirstName" : NumberLong(1),
    "LastName" : NumberLong(1),
    "DateOfBirth" : NumberLong(1),
    "AlternateClientData.FirstName" : NumberLong(1),
    "AlternateClientData.LastName" : NumberLong(1),
    "AlternateClientData.DateOfBirth" : NumberLong(1),
    "AlternateClientData.AccountId" : NumberLong(1)
}
```

Side note: I've argued with the powers that be that we need to take the time to build out a proper searching service using something like Elastic Search but its just not a priority at the moment so I'm stuck with Mongo for now. Is the only thing left to do at the moment to build a separate collection for searching and to flatten + index the searchable data?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of way to create index. One of them you can define indexes on data level( while creating model) like ;

```
@Indexed(sparse = true, 
         unique = false, 
         background = true,
         direction = IndexDirection.ASCENDING, 
         name = "MyIndex",
         expireAfterSeconds = 12000,
         useGeneratedName = false)
@Field("widgetName")
 private String lastname;
```

or you can define by code which is more flexible.
For above problem, I think below compounde index code solves your problem;

```
db.products.createIndex( { "FirstName": 1, "LastName": 1, "DateOfBirth": 1, "AlternateClientData.FirstName": 1 , "AlternateClientData.LastName": 1 , "AlternateClientData.DateOfBirth": 1 , "AlternateClientData.AccountId": 1 } )
```

if any issue for indexes , please look at the official documentation ;
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/

Comment: some of them should be $text indexes, he's using regex. I do not think the arrangement of the index is correct too.

Comment: For text index it is different. You can use only one attribute in collection for this type of index. $regex works for all indexes.

Comment: thx for clarification, I probably mess up with the $text query ops

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The index example you gave is the same as the one I gave that Mongo doesn't use for some reason. Any ideas why it wouldn't use that index? Could it be because the query doesn't always contain a first name and last name? Sometimes it's one or the other.

Comment: what is inside your $match ?